# How can I put a condition on the way of jQuery chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
function startBlinking(el, speed = 100) {
  el.css('display', 'inline').fadeToggle(speed, function() {
    startBlinking(el, speed)
  });
}
```

I want to add one more parameter to the function to make `.css('display', 'inline')` part conditional. Something like this:

```
function startBlinking(el, speed = 100, inlineDisplay = true) {

  if (inlineDisplay){
      el.css('display', 'inline').fadeToggle(speed, function() {
        startBlinking(el, speed)
      });
  } else {
      el.fadeToggle(speed, function() {
        startBlinking(el, speed)
      });
  }
}
```

But the new version looks ugly. I want to know is there any approach to add a condition in the chain?

Comment: Why is it ugly? Also, this question seems to be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not here.

Comment: I'm also wondering why you think it's "ugly"/wrong

Comment: That doesn't look wrong to me .. just duplicate codes makes me feel bad @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, just very similar.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, right ..! I just wanted to know if there is any cleaner way.

Comment: Just don't do chaining.  You already have the result of `.css()` as `el` so you don't *have* to chain it.  Chaining is (partly) there to reduce intermediate variables, which you don't have.   Change to `if (inlineDisplay) { el.css(...); } el.fadeToggle...`

Answer (score 1):

Get the current display value and add a condition for `inlineDisplay` parameter. If `inlineDisplay` is false or `undefined` the current display value will persist else it will be `inline`.

```
function startBlinking(el, speed = 100, inlineDisplay = true) {
    const currentDisplay = el.css('display');
    el.css('display', inlineDisplay ? 'inline' : currentDisplay).fadeToggle(speed, function() {
        startBlinking(el, speed)
      });
}
```